# how can i retrieve email from google api?

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

I am using grails 3.2 and using following plugin:
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1'
 for spring security. I have successfully installed google login. But, I am not able to retrieve gmail id from the plugin.

Comment: Is this OAuth2 ?

Comment: yes...oauth 2 using spring security rest